# if I have a scrollable label (inside a scrollview), how to have it automaticaly scroll at bottom when the text is updated and too long?

Tags: python, scroll, kivy, label

using python and kivy, I have a label in a scrollView that can scroll vertically. The scrolling works perfectly. The content is updated dynamically. And I would like the following behavior : each time the content is updated,

- if the text fits in the visible area, the beginning of the text is aligned with the top of this area.
- if the text is too long to fit in the visible area, the bottom of the text is automatically aligned with the bottom of the visible area when the text is updated by python.

I have tried `self.ids['scroll_view'].scroll_y = 0` like in the following code but it doesn't take account any constraint. It always scrolls to the end of the text.

in .py file :

```
class MyEngine(BoxLayout) :

    display = StringProperty("")

    def update_display(self) :

        #some stuff

        self.display = "some text"   # this string can be long or short

        # here (I suppose) I should measure something to scroll at the bottom iff the text is too long.
        # The above line doesn't care about the text size, it always scrolls at the bottom :

        self.ids['scroll_view'].scroll_y = 0
```

in .kv file :

```
<MyEngine>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size : root.width, root.height
        
        ScrollView:
            id:scroll_view
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                text_size: self.width, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                font_size:'24sp'
                halign: 'left'
                text:root.display

        GridLayout:
            size_hint:1, 0.5
            ...etc....
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a method to adjust the scroll value, and calling that method via `Clock.schedule_once()`, like this:

```
def update_display(self):

    #some stuff

    disp = ''
    for i in range(50):
        disp += "some text " + str(i) + '\n'
    self.display = disp   # this string can be long or short

    Clock.schedule_once(self.adjust_scroll)

    # here (I suppose) I should measure something to scroll at the bottom iff the text is too long.
    # The above line doesn't care about the text size, it always scrolls at the bottom :

    # self.ids['scroll_view'].scroll_y = 0

def adjust_scroll(self, _dt):
    if self.ids.label.height > self.ids.scroll_view.height:
        self.ids['scroll_view'].scroll_y = 0
    else:
        self.ids['scroll_view'].scroll_y = 1
```

The `adjust_scroll()` method needs to be called via `Clock.schedule_once()` in order to allow the `Label` enough time to adjust its `height`.

Comment: thanks @John your solution seems to work fine without Clock.schedule_once